# How We can convert text and image both into a same pdf in React Native?

Tags: react-native, image, text, pdf-generation

Im not able to convert text and image in same pdf while using react native image to pdf ,I need help that how can I convert both text and image to pdf in same pdf file in react native.

I tried React-Native-Image pdf ,but not able to convert Text into same pdf with image. Also I tried to take screenshoot of images and text both and then convert it into pdf but in that case all images and text comes in same page .So I want that in pdf each image and text should be on different pages.So,How can we do this is on same page.If anyone know please help!!!

Comment: I tried this but is is not working even after installing the npm not able to sync the project and not able to make tha build many errors occured in this library